# Suppressing datapath in renderDataTable()

Tags: r, shiny

I looked around but didn't see a solution online, including looking at options, though of course it may have just eluded me.

The problem (see MWE below): Data upload and display properly, but display includes a column containing a long datapath in a `datapath` column, and other columns I don't want (e.g., `type`).

Surely, there's a straightforward way to suppress the display of such columns?

MWE:

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI.
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    fileInput("input_file", 
                    label = "Upload data", 
                    accept = ".csv", 
                    placeholder = "(none)",
                    buttonLabel = "Choose dataset"),

    dataTableOutput("table")
)

# Define the server function for the Shiny app.
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({
            ext <- tools::file_ext(input$input_file$datapath)
            req(input$input_file)
            validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a .csv file."))
            data <- read.csv(input$input_file$datapath)
        })

    output$table <- renderDataTable(input$input_file)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `input$input_file` contains information about the uploaded file, it's path etc. You want to use `data()` (the reactive which contains the read data) within your renderDataTable statement to display the contents of the csv file

Comment: Thank you! To clarify, you are recommending changing `output$table <- renderDataTable(input$input_file)` to `output$table <- renderDataTable(data())`, which renders the data object rather than the list-like input object. That works for me, but I just wanted to write the answer out there for anyone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use columnDefs options inside renderDT:

```
options= list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = c('datapath', 'type')))
```